# How to prevent an aside from closing in angular-strap

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I have a functional angular-strap aside with a custom template.
In my template are anchor tags. When you click one of these tags, it closes the aside.

How can I prevent the aside from closing?

Thanks!

Here is my template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="chart-edit-aside">
<div class="aside" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="aside-dialog">
        <div class="aside-content">
            <div class="aside-header" ng-show="title">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="aside-title" ng-bind="title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="aside-body">
                <div ng-repeat="chart in availablecharts">
                    <a ng-click="loadChartPreview(chart);" href>{{chart.metric_label}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="aside-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-mp" ng-click="saveChart()">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-mp" ng-click="$hide()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my function call on the click event was causing it, when I commented out the body of that func, the aside did not close. So this is not an issue with aside.